# ¿Qué significa *testing.T en go?

Tags: go

Estoy haciendo pruebas unitarias en `Go` y según algunos ejemplos, una función de prueba se define así:

```
func TestAlgo(t *testing.T) {
    ...
}
```

Lo que quiero saber es ¿qué significa exactamente el parámetro de esa función?

También he visto que hacen algo como:

```
func TestAlgo(*testing.B) {
    ...
}
```

¿Cuál es la diferencia con el parámetro anterior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Como lo mencionó, todas los métodos que quiera ejecutarse como pruebas deben declararse de esta forma:

```
func TestAlgo(t *testing.T) {
    ...
}
```

¿Por qué? sencillamente es un contrato entre usted, el programador, y el lenguaje, de tal forma que al ejecutar el comando `go test` Go ejecute las pruebas unitarias de forma unitaria. Para reconocer cuáles son, estas deben implementarse en métodos de la forma

```
func TestXxx(*testing.T)
```

donde cada método comience con la palabra Test y Xxx es cualquier cadena alfanumérica que comience en mayúscula. Adicional a esto, el método debe recibir como argumento una variable de tipo `*testing.T`. Ahora bien ¿qué significa este parámetro? A esté método usted le está pasando un apuntador  a una estructura llamada `T` que se encuentra dentro del paquete `testing`. Este parámetro se pasa a todos los métodos que ejecuten pruebas unitarias ya que la estructura almacena información sobre el estado de las pruebas y el formato en el que debe imprimir los logs si así lo desea durante la ejecución de la prueba. [Aquí](https://golang.org/src/testing/testing.go#L294) puede ver el código fuente en el que se declara esta estructura.

La diferencia entre

```
func TestAlgo(t *testing.T) {
    ... 
}
```

y

```
func TestAlgo(*testing.B) {
    ...
}
```

es que en realidad el segundo método no se ejecutará como una prueba unitaria automática, porque no cumple el contrato que requiere Go porque recibe un apuntador a una estructura de tipo `B` dentro del paquete `testing`. Esta estructura `B` hace referencia a un tipo de dato que se usa para ejecutar pruebas benchmark, o de rendimiento, que desee incluir. Sin embargo, la correcta declaración de los métodos que quieran ejecutarse así es:

```
func BenchmarkXxx(*testing.B) {
    ...
}
```

Ahora, si en realidad hace referencia a la diferencia entre

```
func TestAlgo(t *testing.T) {
    ... 
}
```

y

```
func TestAlgo(*testing.T) {
    ...
}
```

(ambos con parámetro apuntador a una estructura de tipo `T` en el paquete `testing`) es que en realidad no hay ninguna diferencia. En Go, el nombre de la variable en los argumentos de las funciones no es estrictamente necesario, sólo el tipo. Sin embargo, si quiere realizar algo como:

```
func TestAlgo(*testing.T) {
    //Método de ejecución de la prueba
    //Si ocurre un error, imprima un mensaje ó marque la prueba como fallida.
}
```

necesitará usar el nombre de la variable para llamar a los métodos disponibles en T para imprimir errores, por lo tanto, sí deberá declarar el nombre de la variable también, que la referencia normalmente la denomina `t`:

```
func TestAlgo(t *testing.T) {
    a = 1
    if a != 2 {
        t.Error("1 no es igual a 2)
    }
}
```

En la [documentación](https://godoc.org/testing) de Go hay más información al respecto.